# NetBeans: use the Swing GUI or programmatically create the GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I know the answer to my question will be something along the lines of "depends on what you want to do", but I have the feeling that I have way more control over what's happening if I programmatically create the elements of my GUI.
Could you guys let me know when it would be advised/better to use the NetBeans Swing GUI (possibly providing an example) and vice versa?
Thanks.

Comment: IMHO - Hand code - it won't lock you into a editor and will force you to learn better practices

Comment: The answer posted by MadProgrammer pretty much answers my question. Thanks

Comment: Or try my guide to making GUI in Netbeans. http://philofjava.webstarts.com/